# Continuous over two variables implies continuous over one variable

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm trying to reconcile the results of two exercises in Terence Tao's *Analysis II*, and I feel as though my confusion comes from a misunderstanding of the concepts.

Exercise 2.2.9

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $f$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$, show that $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}\limsup\limits_{y\rightarrow y_0}f(x,y)=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow y_0}\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)$$ and $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}\liminf\limits_{y\rightarrow y_0}f(x,y)=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow y_0}\liminf\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0).$$ In particular, we have $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow y_0}f(x,y)=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow y_0}\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x,y)$$ whenever the limits  on both sides exist. (Note that the limits do not necessarily exist in general; consider for instance the function such that $f(x,y)=y\sin\frac{1}{x}$ when $xy\neq0$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.)

Exercise 2.2.10

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the function $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and for each $y\in\mathbb{R}$, the function $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

(These are slightly paraphrased for brevity)

2.2.10 seems to work if "continuous" is replaced with "continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$," which would imply that if we hold $x$ constant, $\limsup\limits_{y\rightarrow y_0}f(x,y)= \lim\limits_{y\rightarrow y_0}f(x,y)=f(x,y_0)$, and likewise if we interchange $x$ and $y$, and then 2.2.9 follows. However, this means there is no reason to introduce $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ and no reason to worry about whether the limits on both sides exist; if either of them don't, then $f(x,y)$ is not continuous, so the conditions from 2.2.9 don't apply.

This also seems to invalidate the counterexample given in 2.2.9. We can see $f(x,y)$ is continuous when $x\neq0$ and at $(0,0)$, so the limits on both sides exist, by 2.2.10. However, $f(x,y)$ is not continuous when $x=0$ and $y\neq0$, so the conditions from 2.2.9 don't apply.

What am I missing or misunderstanding in these problems? Is there a better counterexample to use in conjunction with Exercise 2.2.9?

Comment: In 2.2.9, there is "moevement" in both directions. Whereas in 2.2.9, there is only "movement" in one. Sure, you can fix "x" or "y", but you can't know what happens as you take limits there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to break it down :

1. Yes, you are correct. A function is continuous on a domain, if it is continuous at every point of it's domain.
2. What you are misunderstanding is the function given by Prof. Tao, in the sense that the function given has no well defined limit at $(0,0)$, as  $ \lim_{x \to 0} \sin(1/x) = $ doesn't exist. And this is precisely his point with the limits. You can take $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \lim_{y \to 0} \: y\sin{1/x}$$ and it's indeed $0$. However, if you change the order of the limits : $$\lim_{y \to 0} \lim_{x \to 0}\:  y\sin{1/x}$$ Then you have a problem. This limit is not well defined. However, the limit of the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are.
3. Only in the case of continuous functions, can you have the property $ \lim \liminf f = \lim \limsup f$ hold everywhere, for both $x$ and $y$, regardless of their order.

I hope my point was somewhat clear.

Comment: Well, for your first point, what I was saying was that an almost identical proof shows that you can change $f$ from a function continuous at *all* points to a function continuous at *a specific point*, and it still works. Your second point cleared up my confusion, though, so thank you; I've accepted your answer.

Comment: @StephenGoree Yes, that's why i said you were correct. I can see now that i wasn't specific enough in my first point. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

> 2.2.10 seems to work if "continuous" is replaced with "continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$
> ," which would imply that if we hold $x$
> constant, $\limsup\limits_{y\to y_0} f(x,y) = \lim\limits_{y\to y_0}f(x,y) = f(x,y_0)$

This is not true. You can only conclude that
$$\limsup_{y\to y_0}f(x_0, y) = f(x_0, y_0)$$
In your proof of 2.2.10, you likely used the fact that $f$ is continuous at $(x,y_0)$ for $any$ $x$ to conclude that $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous at $y_0$ for $any$ $x$. But in 2.2.9, you are only given that $f$ is continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$.